# Split function in dynamic loop in python

Tags: python, split

I am using a dynamic loop with `split` function, but unable to split:

```
lst= [int(x) for x in input("Enter elements").split('--')]

print(lst)
```

Output:
Enter elements 123456

[123456]

It doesn't split with "--"

Expected output: [1--2--3--4--5--6]

Comment: @nofinator It gives the list as it is, but doesn't split the list with ","

Comment: @Gsk but even if i split it with some other symbol suppose "--" it gives me the list as it is

Comment: @TamanbirSingh Please refer [how to split a string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to *join* the chars and put them inside a list:

```
txt = input("Enter elements: ")
# type 123456

['--'.join(str(txt))]
=> ['1--2--3--4--5--6']
```